# Replacing window and wood siding

Tags: windows, siding

I have a bathroom window in the shower. The window drains down onto the wood siding causing it constantly peel. We would like to put a shorter window in and higher up to avoid this. How tough would it be to match our current wood siding? Or do you think if we replaced the current window but installed better so it drains proper, hay would solve our issue? The window doesn’t sits oddly in the opening.

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to fix the drainage problem instead and keep the window? Is the water falling in the window track and exiting through weep holes? Or is it exiting some other way?

Comment: It does come out of the weep holes and then runs down the trim.

Comment: Why not improvise something to sit in the window's track that slopes to shed the water back into the shower? (The weep holes move water from inside the window's track to outside.) If this window is actually in the shower, then I expect that you don't open it frequently.

Comment: Well we would like to be able to crack the window for ventilation. That is why we are thinking about making a smaller window.

Comment: Have you already tried repainting at least once? If so, how many times? Did you prime? Did the fresh paint quickly peel again, unlike neighboring areas of paint with similar sun exposure?

Comment: I think I see some kind of water stain on the left, but not the right. Is there a spot for the left weep hole to drain behind the trim? Is it possible to caulk the trim so that water must drain off the face of the trim instead of behind it?

Comment: What does the shower look like? Is it definitely water proof, like one of those single-piece shower inserts? Or is it possible that there's a moisture problem in the wall cavity, like a tiled shower? Is there access to the back side of the shower controls from a panel in another room?